# How to show number of result count of ngIf?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
<div class="prod-div results" *ngIf="product.name.indexOf(searchProd$ | async |lowercase) !== -1 
                || product.details.indexOf(searchProd$ | async |lowercase) !== -1">
```

And I want to show this

```
{{ searchCount() }} search results for "{{ searchProd$ | async }}"
```

I used this code:

```
searchCount() {
    let num = document.getElementsByClassName('results');
    console.log (num.length);
    return num.length;
  }
```

The problem is it does not dynamically update, lets say the results should be 6 for 'a', it shows 0 and only updates to 6 if I click the screen or type another key.

EDIT: I get this error core.js:6486 ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '0'. Current value: '6'

Comment: I think you can count it directly from your list of product objects. What do you think?

Comment: I get this error core.js:6486 ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '0'. Current value: '6'

Comment: Currently the function `searchCount()` will be invoked every time the change detection cycle runs. Thus, the recommended approach would be to use a custom event to invoke the function `searchCount()`

Comment: try {{ (searchProd$ | async).length }} instead of {{ searchCount() }}

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a trigger in component.ts

```
ngAfterViewInit(){

searchCount();

}
```

or you can use any other life cycle hook.

Comment: I still get error Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '0'. Current value: '6'

Comment: Then please try ngAfterContentInit() { searchCount();}

Comment: I think I should only invoke search count when the search input changes but how do I do that?

Comment: No worries. You need something like document.ready equivalent which we used in JS. For angular it is  ngAfterViewInit(). Please check the updated answer.